# mySQL query to return results that have a duplicate field?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mySQL table which contains rows based on payments.

Each row contains their e-mail address, so I want to write a query using mySQL and PHP to find out how many people have 2 or more entries in this table.

This is basically to know if they have paid us more than once, by buying two packages, or renewing a subscription.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: What you have tried ? Code please

Comment: `select unique_id, count(*) from table_name group by unique_id;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select distinct email, count(*) as rowcount
from datatable
group by email
having rowcount > 1
```

EDIT: I wrote the above off the top of my head. A quick test on Oracle shows that the syntax is slightly wrong and should be

```
select distinct email, count(*) as rowcount
from datatable
group by email
having count(*) > 1
```

But this might just be Oracle not allowing the aliased column in the having clause. I'm not sure what mySQL would allow.

Comment: You don't need DISTINCT clause.

Comment: Yes, you're quite correct and I didn't do that on my test, but for some reason when I typed it in to my answer, I put it in!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT email, COUNT(email) as c_email FROM emails_table WHERE c_email > 1;
```

Comment: You will not be able to use `c_email` in the `WHERE` clause, as this only accepts column names. To filter on an aggregate or column alias, you will need to use `HAVING c_email > 1`

Comment: This is also missing the aggregate clause - GROUP BY